# ReactJS Component Architecture Problems / Nested Components or Single Component Manager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm currently building an icon component in ReactJS, It's going to have maybe 50-100 icons, all using SVG and path data.

I'm in a situation where I want to know which route I would be best advancing and why said route would be the better choice. I've thought of two options which could be viable and could see benefits in both.

---

#### Option 1

- Create One component named 'Icon'
- Take a prop called 'name' (this will reference the icon name)
- Based on the prop name show the appropriate svg
- One Single component for all icons

---

#### Option 2

- Create a component named 'Icon'
- Create individual components for each Icon e.g (ArrowLeft, Hamburger)
- Individual component inherit 'Icon' as the parent
- Parent component holds all SVG information
- Child component holds only path data
- 50-100 Icon components

---

I would consider using **Option 1** as the cleaner approach to my file system, I can imagine the file size of a bundle being smaller for production ready code.

I've started to code up both options and would really like some input. Especially if there is a better method I haven't thought of yet.

Here's some code:-

---

### Option 1

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import _ from 'lodash';
import '../../global.js';
import * as variable from '../../variables.js';

const iconList = {
    navigation: {
        arrowUp: 'path data here',
        hamburger: 'path data here'
  }
}

class Icon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        let width, height, data, name;

        width = this.props.width === undefined ? '25' : this.props.width;
        height = this.props.height === undefined ? '25' : this.props.height;

        name = this.props.name;

        _.forEach(iconList, function(value, key) {
            data = _.get(value, [name]);
        });


        const icon = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 25 25">
                         <path fill={this.props.color} d={data} fillRule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>;

        return (
                <IconStyle>
                    {icon}
                </IconStyle>
        )

    }
}

export default Icon;
```

---

### Option 2 - (Icon.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

import '../../global.js';
import * as variable from '../../variables.js';

const IconStyle = styled.div `
    display:inline-block;
`;

class Icons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        let width, height;

        width = this.props.width === undefined ? '25' : this.props.width;
        height = this.props.height === undefined ? '25' : this.props.height;


        const icon = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 25 25">
                         <path fill={this.props.color} d={this.props.data} fillRule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>;

        return (
                <IconStyle>
                    {icon}
                </IconStyle>
        )

    }
}


export default Icons;
```

### Option 2 - Hamburger.js (Inherits Icon)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import '../../../global.js';
import * as variable from '../../../variables.js';
import Icon from '../Icon';

class NavigationHamburger extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {


        let data = "M6.34 8.14c-.45 0-.8-.36-.8-.8 0-.45.35-.8.8-.8h12c.44 0 .8.35.8.8 0 .44-.36.8-.8.8h-12zm12 8.4c.44 0 .8.35.8.8 0 .44-.36.8-.8.8h-12c-.45 0-.8-.36-.8-.8 0-.45.35-.8.8-.8h12zm0-5c.44 0 .8.35.8.8 0 .44-.36.8-.8.8h-12c-.45 0-.8-.36-.8-.8 0-.45.35-.8.8-.8h12z";

        return (
                <Icon data={data} {...this.props} />           
        )

    }
}

NavigationHamburger.PropTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.color,
    width: PropTypes.boolean,
    height: PropTypes.boolean
}

export default NavigationHamburger;
```

With **Option 2** I would just call the component using

`<NavigationHamburger width={30} height={30} color="#000"/`>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also go for the **first** approach:

1. Approach

   - + Less code
   - + Easier to maintain (Faster to add a new Icon)
   - + No code duplication
   - - Chance of typos in the name (Maybe you could work with some sort of javascript enums)
2. Approach

   - + Easier to use (Defined components, no names)
   - - Hard to maintain (Change code in every file)
   - - Massive more code
   - - Not scalable

So I would take the first approch, but I will also add this file for an easier use:

IconTypes.js:

```
const IconTypes = {
  HAMBURGER: 'hamburger'
}

export default IconTypes;
```

Now you have eliminated the chance of typos, since you get a lint error. You can now call the icon like this (after Importing the Icon and IconType class):

```
<Icon name={iconTypes.HAMBURGER} width={30} height={30} color="#000" />
```

I hope this answer showed you some points and helped you make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** is quite better compared to **Option 2**. Firstly, the reusability plays its part to the maximum. There will be one component and you'll be using it every time with different props. Secondly, if you go with **Option 2**, the file structure will be messy. By messy, I mean you will have a separate file for each icon and you'll have overhead time while bundling and compiling. For some betterment, I'd suggest that you take this path mapping to another file and not do it in the component:

```
const iconList = {
  navigation: {
    arrowUp: 'path data here',
    hamburger: 'path data here'
  }
}
```